# OAuth Login - UserID from ProviderUserId

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, .net-4.5

I want to do something simple, so must be missing something.  I've added some information to UserProfile and want to display that by the username in the "Welcome [username]" section.  So I also wanted to have a `UserProfile CurrentUser` to have access to the current users information from the database in session.  I've been all through the `WebSecurity` and `OAuthWebSecurity` class and can't figure out how to get the current UserId or current UserProfile instance.  I do see `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId`, but it is -1 after coming in with a Microsoft account.  So in simplist terms, how do I get the current UserId or UserProfile when a user uses Microsoft, Facebook or other services to log in so I can set it in `ExternalLoginCallback()`?  I know the relationship is there in the database.

Thanks for any help or enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that during the current action `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` is -1 but is populated correctly later in the process and is accessible in subsequent actions.  In my case, I setup an ajax call to get the information and display it on the screen as the page loads.